GammaMaP package symbolic output
I'm new in Mathematica and I've just installed the GammaMaP package. The problem is that I'm not getting the a symbolic output like in the documentation, for example, if I create a cell with the code y[{u[µ,ν],d[σ]},{u[a,b]}], when I evaliate it, I get the output y[{u[µ,ν],d[σ]},{u[a,b]}], not the one with the proper nottaion γµ,νσγa,b, like in the documentation.
I've checked every step on the installation of the package and on the Mathematica documentation, but because I'm new, I don't really now where I should look.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There is an SE forum for Mathematica questions: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/
